# How to remove files that are listed in the .gitignore but still on the repository?

Tags: git, ignore, gitignore

I have some files in my repository that should be ignored, i added them to the .gitignore but, of course, they are not removed from my repository.

So my question is, is there a magic command or script using filter-branch that can rewrite my history and remove all these files easily? Or simply a command that will create a commit that will remove them ?

Comment: Duplicate of [.gitignore file not ignoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: WARNING: While this will not remove the physical file from your local, it will remove the files from other developers machines on next git pull. [How to make Git “forget” about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: @Stevoisiak this is not a duplicate of that question because this one asks about ALL ignored files and it also has a better answer than any of the similar questions.

Comment: You need to add the `.gitignore` file, too.

Answer (score 788, accepted):

You can remove them from the repository manually:

```
git rm --cached file1 file2 dir/file3
```

Or, if you have a lot of files:

```
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i -c --exclude-from=.gitignore`
```

But this doesn't seem to work in Git Bash on Windows. It produces an error message. The following works better:

```
git ls-files -i -c --exclude-from=.gitignore | xargs git rm --cached
```

In PowerShell on Windows this works even better (handles spaces in path and filenames):

```
git ls-files -i -c --exclude-from=.gitignore | %{git rm --cached $_}
```

Regarding rewriting the whole history without these files, I highly doubt there's an *automatic* way to do it.
And we all know that rewriting the history is bad, don't we? :)

Comment: Unfortunately the Git Bash on Windows command doesn't work with paths that contain spaces

Comment: @NateBundy if you're referring to the fact that `xargs` won't work with spaces, most command line utilities get around that by using special flags so that whitespace won't matter. Off the top of my head I don't remember what the flags are for `git ls-files` and `xargs` (I think it might be `-0` for `xargs`), but you can look them up.

Comment: wrong, wrong, and wrong.  :(  sorry no insight, yeah git needs to add a feature that doesn't make this particular thing - which totally sucks ass and eats up tons of coding time - not suck so bad

Comment: `git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore``   seems working now. Windows10,  git version  2.19.1

Comment: None of these work in Windows, they all just print the usage for `git rm`

Comment: "git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore" is very helpful, it tells me what files are excluded by .ignore.

Comment: I was happy to find these commands, BUT it does not really remove the files from repository. When i removed 2300 kB of images, repository size dropped only 10 kB. So it cannot be used, for example, to make repository smaller and faster to transfer.

Comment: And if you have way too many files to remove and bash is complaining that the arguments are too long, you can successively do `git rm --cached \`git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore\` | head -n 100`

Comment: the last part (code) for windows is a working solution for my usage case.

Comment: Note that regardless of your current directory, `--exclude-from=` is relative to the git root. So if you want to do this for a .gitignore in a subdirectory, use `--exclude-from=[subdirectory]/.gitignore`.

Comment: cmd `git rm --cached -r dirName` worked in Windows 7 to recursively delete all files in a folder.

Comment: On Windows 10 Git bash command line the command "git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore`"  worked fine.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: do not forget to commit: `git commit -m "Drop files from .gitignore"` !

Comment: Uhhhhhh what do I do if `git rm --cached \`git ls-files -i -c --exclude-from=.gitignore\`` gives me `-bash: /usr/bin/git: Argument list too long`  (not my repo!) // I checked and there's 24862 files that should have been ignored but weren't. Wish me luck!

Comment: The PowerShell script removed good files too. Use with care.

Comment: yikes, why so complicated? i accidentally committed some sensitive information and just want it removed quickly, i don't understand why there isn't like a "refresh" option that sweeps items from a gitignore out of the repository.... but then again Git rarely makes sense to me...

Comment: On Linux both suggested methods failed due to spaces in the file path. Luckily nothing got deleted by accident. Improper handling of spaces in paths can be extremely dangerous, so I suggest to replace the suggested Bash commands with the following, which handles spaces correctly: `git ls-files -i -c --exclude-from=.gitignore | xargs -d \\n git rm --cached`

Comment: `git rm --cached file1 file2 dir/file3` worked for me on Git Bash on Windows. Just remember to put -r for folders.

Answer (score 666):

An easier way that works regardless of the OS is to do

```bash
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Drop files from .gitignore"
```

You basically remove and re-add all files, but `git add` will ignore the ones in `.gitignore`.

Using the `--cached` option will keep files in your filesystem, so you won't be removing files from your disk.

Note:
Some pointed out in the comments that you will lose the history of all your files. I tested this with git 2.27.0 on MacOS and it is *not* the case. If you want to check what is happening, check your `git diff HEAD~1` before you push your commit.

Comment: How does this effect other users on the repo executing a *pull* - as I read it the folder we dont want to track anymore is deleted??? How can we prevent this - we just want to untrack

Comment: This will mark all the files as changed with a fake commit message !

Comment: what do you mean by fake commit message? It's a real commit message :P
You can change the message of course, depending on your needs...

Comment: Just for a completeness sake you need git push command at the end.

Comment: Don't do this, it will remove history on all the files

Comment: @agrath What if you don't care about that history?  In my present situation the files in question are log files from debugging sessions.  Why waste space with their history?

Comment: @agrath where did you test this? Which version of git? Which OS?
It is not the case for me on MacOS and git 2.27.0

Comment: Just to clarify a bit because the `git status` after doing `git rm -r --cached .` `git add .` can look a bit scary:  These three commands that @gtatr provides essentially delete files from git that were previously tracked, but have since been added to your .gitignore file.  When I first ran this, I saw a bunch of files and freaked out for a second but upon further inspection I noticed they were all files that were listed in my .gitignore file.

Comment: This should absolutely be the accepted answer, and you don't remote the history of the files (anyway you can check always before committing). Just did against my repo on GitHub, perfectly removed all unwanted files and history is still there! Thanks!

Comment: @agrath, You should remove your comment or clarify it. I cannot confirm that the history of any file would be removed.

Comment: @simon I am unable to edit my comment and as it was made roughly 3 years ago I don't remember the specifics. I think what I meant is that if you take this approach, the files you are removing (due to gitignore) will get removed from your commit history entirely. Meaning, you'd be unable to see that file ever existed. For something like a log file, that would be fine, of course. 
This behaviour may have changed since then, or perhaps when I tested this I mistyped something. The OP seems to wish to remove the history anyway.

Comment: @agrath, ok, thank you for the clarification, I now get what you mean (commit history and gitignore). I think that has not changed, but should rarely be a problem I think.

Comment: that removes my full project.

Comment: @AnjanBiswas - it depends on what you have in your gitignore...

Comment: @gtatr I got your point. I was wrong. I need to commit again and push my code. it didn't remove my previous git history. Thanks a lot, man.

Comment: This works and does NOT remove complete git history. 
Only removes `.gitignore` files.  Tested on git version 2.39.2.windows.1

Comment: Unbelievable. So many ups for an answer that has absolutely no connection to the question. All files remain in the repository and in the history. The question was about how to delete the files from the history according to the current .gitignore file.

Answer (score 217):

As the files in **.gitignore** are not being tracked, you can use the **git clean** command to recursively remove files that are not under version control.

Use `git clean -xdn` to perform a dry run and see what will be removed.
Then use `git clean -xdf` to execute it.

Basically, `git clean -h` or `man git-clean`(in unix) will give you help.

Be aware that this command will also remove **new files** that are not in the staging area.

Comment: This answer isn't applicable - the OP says the files in `.gitignore` *are* being tracked.

Comment: BEWARE! This permanently deletes all untracked files, rather than just removing from the branch

Comment: the `git clean -xdn` is a dry run which won't delete. the next one will.

Comment: -1: This is a highly misleading answer - the original poster wanted to remove from the repository, not remove the files completely. I was this close to deleting a load of dynamic files required by my IDE but not required to be in the repo.

Comment: It was actually helpful for me but missleading. Probably better as a comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

I did a very straightforward solution by manipulating the output of the .gitignore statement with sed:

```bash
cat .gitignore | sed '/^#.*/ d' | sed '/^\s*$/ d' | sed 's/^/git rm -r /' | bash
```

Explanation:

1. print the .gitignore file
2. remove all comments from the print
3. delete all empty lines
4. add 'git rm -r ' to the start of the line
5. execute every line.

Comment: `sed` is straightforward?

Comment: Siilar example with another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63534476/7127519

Comment: +1 for scripting and explaining it.  Explaining the danger of running it right into bash without review may have been an oversight.

Comment: This is not robust. Some gitignore files use a whitelist mode where they ignore everything but exclude what needs to be kept using "!"

Answer (score 6):

`git rm --cached -r .`
to remove all cached recursively

`git add .`
to add all files not included in .gitignore

you will have to commit some deleted files that are not really deleted on File System

using a single command it will be
`git rm --cached -r . && git add .`

Answer (score 4):

"[`git clean`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/33be431c0c7284c1adf0fe49f7838dbc8aee6ea9/Documentation/git-clean.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean))</sup> and [`git ls-files -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/33be431c0c7284c1adf0fe49f7838dbc8aee6ea9/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L51)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--i))</sup> had confusion around working on or showing ignored paths inside an ignored directory, which has been corrected with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021).

That means the 2021 version of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541721/6309) would be:

```
git ls-files -i -c --exclude-from=.gitignore | xargs git rm --cached  
                ^^
```

See [commit b548f0f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b548f0f1568f6b01e55ca69c24d3cb19489f92aa), [commit dd55fc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd55fc0df15c338a8dbec6dec6ca6b58edc8acef), [commit aa6e1b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa6e1b21e5de8fae7121b8c6543e1482144c1ed3), [commit a97c7a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a97c7a8bc4f2068b2e8c23ce8d17f7db8333ded0), [commit 2e4e43a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e4e43a6910393d681d095f515d41232c2372966), [commit b338e9f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b338e9f668737e08201c990450b8c3d744f63162), [commit 7fe1ffd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fe1ffdafa56b8453a47a40b866d029f24a56d76), [commit 7f9dd87](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f9dd87922c9065c8adcea1469c3caf3b3af2afa) (12 May 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit 4e689d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e689d81718eb6e939cace317ea3e33cb994dcbb) (12 May 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 33be431](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33be431c0c7284c1adf0fe49f7838dbc8aee6ea9), 20 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`ls-files`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b338e9f668737e08201c990450b8c3d744f63162): error out on -i unless -o or -c are specified
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> [`ls-files --ignored`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b338e9f668737e08201c990450b8c3d744f63162/Documentation/git-ls-files.txt#L52)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---ignored))</sup> can be used together with either `--others` or `--cached`.
>
> After being perplexed for a bit and digging in to the code, I assumed that `ls-files -i` was just broken and not printing anything and I had a nice patch ready to submit when I finally realized that `-i` can be used with `--cached` to find tracked ignores.
>
> While that was a mistake on my part, and a careful reading of the documentation could have made this more clear, I suspect this is an error others are likely to make as well.
> In fact, of two uses in our testsuite, I believe one of the two did make this error.
> In t1306.13, there are NO tracked files, and all the excludes built up and used in that test and in previous tests thus have to be about untracked files.
> However, since they were looking for an empty result, the mistake went unnoticed as their erroneous command also just happened to give an empty answer.
>
> `-i` will most the time be used with `-o`, which would suggest we could just make `-i` imply `-o` in the absence of either a `-o` or `-c`, but that would be a backward incompatible break.
> Instead, let's just flag `-i` without either a `-o` or `-c` as an error, and update the two relevant testcases to specify their intent.

That means without `-c`, you would get (starting with Git 2.32, Q2 2021):

```
fatal: ls-files -i must be used with either -o or -c
```

Note: this is still a work in progress, since it was [reverted in Git 2.32-rc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c9f1bfdb47acde21052bb33ff083347cbcb574d) but fixed with [commit 2c9f1bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c9f1bfdb47acde21052bb33ff083347cbcb574d), [commit 1df046b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1df046bcff6085f3800088c51e344594f822df57) (27 May 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 906fc55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/906fc557b70b2b2995785c9b37e212d2f86b469e) (27 May 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit eef8148](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eef814828f175290ca1fcd17ad74faff95346c85) (27 May 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 329d63e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/329d63e7be044524d29dcb43e8ed52bc1f3b9241), 28 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`dir`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/906fc557b70b2b2995785c9b37e212d2f86b469e): introduce `readdir_skip_dot_and_dotdot()` helper
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This solution adds carriage returns (I'm a WSL user, so this is important), and parenthesis escaping (which is important to LaTeX users sometimes, e.g. `*.synctex(busy)`).

---

Inspired by [Scott's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46494462/9564132):

```sh
cat .gitignore | sed "s/\r//" | sed -r "/^(#.*|\s*)$/d" | sed -r "s/([()])/\\\\\1/g" | sed "s/^/git rm -r /" | bash
```

1. Remove: carriage returns (`s/\r//`).
2. Remove lines containing: comments (`/^#.*$/`), empty line groups (`/^\s*$/`, matches whitespace or empty line). Notice the pipe `|` character, this is standard regex, and requires `-r` (although I believe `-E` also works).
3. Replace: parenthesis `/([()])/` with its escaped version `\\\1`, `\1` matches the group, in this case it means `[()]`, or `(` or `)`, whatever was matched. Notice the `g` flag, this is to match (and replace) *all* parenthesis. Could be rewritten as `"s/(\(|\))/\\\\\1/g"` if you're into that.
4. Prepend `git rm -r`

Replacement looks like `s/$old/$new/$flags`. Removal looks like `/$old/d`. Prepending is replacing `/^/`. And you could do appending by replacing `/$/`. And of course, some characters are escaped, since you can't make raw strings in bash as far as I know. Finally, this line can be condensed, but I chose to leave it expanded for the sake of readability.

---

I saw someone questioning (in Scott's solution) that `sed` is straight forward. I like to think of this method as the most basic and most monkey-way to do it, this is good, because if you ever need a variation of this, you can make it on the spot. And if anything, it's a good excuse to practice regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to prune your history of `.gitignore`d files, first save `.gitignore` outside the repo, e.g. as `/tmp/.gitignore`, then run

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
    "git ls-files -i -X /tmp/.gitignore -c | xargs -r git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -rf" \
    --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Notes:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning is not just there for fun
- `git filter-branch --index-filter` runs in the `.git` directory I think, i.e. if you want to use a relative path you have to prepend one more `../` first. And apparently you cannot use `../.gitignore`, the actual `.gitignore` file, that yields a "fatal: cannot use ../.gitignore as an exclude file" for some reason (maybe during a `git filter-branch --index-filter` the working directory is (considered) empty?)
- I was hoping to use something like `git ls-files -iX <(git show $(git hash-object -w .gitignore))` instead to avoid copying `.gitignore` somewhere else, but that alone already returns an empty string (whereas `cat <(git show $(git hash-object -w .gitignore))` indeed prints `.gitignore`'s contents as expected), so I cannot use `<(git show $GITIGNORE_HASH)` in `git filter-branch`...
- If you actually only want to `.gitignore`-clean a specific branch, replace `--all` in the last line with its name. The `--tag-name-filter cat` might not work properly then, i.e. you'll probably not be able to directly transfer a single branch's tags properly

Comment: This is not recommended https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning

Answer (score -1):

In linux you can use this command:

For example I want to delete `*.py~` so my command should be ==>

`find . -name "*.py~" -exec rm -f {} \;`

Answer (score -1):

For GitHub, the **easiest** way is to open the **online VS Code editor** by pressing `.` when viewing the repo. Then you can just right-click and delete the files/folders in the left hand panel and commit the change.

[image: VS Code Source Control]

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution to remove files already committed but now in `.gitignore`, execute these commands:

```bash
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore`
git commit -m "Remove ignored files"
```

This will remove the files from the repository (keeping them in your working directory) and create a commit for the changes.

Answer (score -2):

Simply go to gitignore file and remove whatever added newly and then commit the changes, it remove contents from there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

The git will ignore the files matched .gitignore pattern after you add it to .gitignore.

But the files already existed in repository will be still in.

use `git rm files_ignored; git commit -m 'rm no use files'` to delete ignored files.

Comment: There are a lot of them, is there a way to delete them without having to specifying their names?