# .gitignore is still not ignoring files despite removal

Tags: git, gitlab

I know there are many, many posts on this topic. I've tried all of the answers I can find and none of them seem to be addressing my problem.

I started a git project where unfortunately `.pyc` files in `__pycache__` directories were initially being tracked. I realised the problem and then put `*.pyc` and `__pycache__` in .gitignore, but of course they were still being tracked.

I then:

- Tried to remove the tracked files:

  ```
  git rm -r --cached .
  git add .
  git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
  ```
- Checked my .gitignore. The encoding, according to `file -I .gitignore`, is `.gitignore: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`. The .gitignore itself is:

  ```
  __pycache__
  *.pyc
  buildSite/.DS_Store
  *.DS_Store
  .idea/
  .idea/workspace.xml
  scratchFiles
  ```

  There aren't any extra whitespaces or anything.

I'm still getting .pyc files showing changes:

```
git status
...
modified:   buildSite/builder/templatetags/__pycache__/class_tag.cpython-36.pyc
```

Very grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: did you commit your .gitignore file before running `git rm -r --cached .`?

Comment: Yes - is that a problem?

Comment: I thought it might be a problem if you hadn't committed it, but never mind now

Comment: Try `git ls-files -i -z --exclude-from=.gitignore | xargs -0 git rm --cached` as suggested in [How to remove files that are listed in the .gitignore but still on the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541615/how-to-remove-files-that-are-listed-in-the-gitignore-but-still-on-the-repositor); then `git commit -m "Fix untracked files"`

Comment: `.gitignore` works even if not committed — `git` consults files, not commits. It would be interesting to see `git status` after `git rm` and `git add`.

Comment: Also check for simple PEBCAK: was `.` the right directory when you ran `git rm -r --cached .`?

Comment: I had whitespaces before __pycache__ and *.pyc, which caused it to not ignore *.pyc and __pycache__ directories. Removing the whitespace fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure:

- there is no crlf in your `.gitignore` file
- there is no nested git repo (`.git/` subolder) in any parent folder of your files to be ignored
- there is a trailing / when ignoring a folder: `__pycache__/`, not `__pycache__`.

Comment: This was it, thanks! In messing with my `.gitignore` trying to figure out what was going on, I deleted the trailing `/` before running `git rm - r --cached .`.