# Why does .gitignore does not work in Pycharm? It still track the change in the file under ./idea

Tags: python, git, pycharm, gitignore

I have set up the project interpreter in Pycharm for a my team project. I have cloned it from Git. We have listed the file under .idea folder in the .gitignore. But everytime I set the project interpreter, Pycharm track these file as the changed file. Here is our gitignore

```
*.pyc
doc/.*
partner/.*
.settings/
doc
tests/test.py
tests/format_db.py
nohup.out
crawler/uber.py
.idea/*
.vscode/*
broadcast.log
last_commit.txt
```

Comment: None of those duplicates address Pycharm.  None of them do.

Answer (score 13):

You have to remove files from git's cache.

```
git rm --cached file1 file2 dir/file3
```

---

source: [How to remove files that are listed in the .gitignore but still on the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541615/how-to-remove-files-that-are-listed-in-the-gitignore-but-still-on-the-repositor#13541721)