# VS gitignore issues

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I’m having trouble in visual studio where it sees .cache files as changes.

I added .cache extensions to my gitignore file, but no luck.

Example file path : obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/win7-x64/MyProject.assets.cache

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove files that are listed in the .gitignore but still on the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541615/how-to-remove-files-that-are-listed-in-the-gitignore-but-still-on-the-repositor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository) answer you can do the following commands:**

- First commit any code changes, and then, run this command:
  `git rm -r --cached .`
- This removes any changed files from staging area, then just run:
  `git add .`
- Commit it:
  `git commit -m "Your commit"`