# How to show only one file changed in commit?

Tags: git, github

I have made changes to one file and two files were put in gitignore file. When I do a commit, it should only show as 1 file changed, instead of 3 files changed. How can I do that?

I tried committing files but it shows 3 files changed.

Comment: Try to commit `.gitignore` file first, then the others. If the problem persists, ensure that your `.gitignore` is correct, and that you don't use `-f` (force add) flag.

Comment: Your files may have been pushed to git already. If so, try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541721

Comment: `.gitignore` only works for files that are _not_ tracked.

Comment: So, what I actually want to do is when I do a commit, it should only show as 1 file changed instead of 3 files changed

Comment: Those three files are `changed`, not `newly added`, right? Then you have to `git rm` them first to get them out of the repo.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl, Sorry for the late reply. I have to delete two files and I have made changes in one file. So, when I do a commit, it should reflect as only 1 file changed, instead of 3 files changed. I do not want to track the two files that I have deleted.

Comment: Short answer: no. When the file is in the repo already and you delete it now, that is a change that needs to be reflected in the repo. When you delete the file, this change has to be committed (and pushed) so that the files will also be gone in your remote repository (github or whatever)

Comment: What do you want? Do you have a file in the repo and want to ignore all future changes? Do you want to delete it locally but keep it in the remote repo?