# Although I add venv and db.sqlite3 to .gitignore, git pushes these files too

Tags: git, gitignore

I created a .gitignore file and added these things as different rows:

```
__pycache__
db.sqlite3
.env
venv/
```

When I follow the routine way (add . -> commit -> push -u origin main), .gitignore works for `.env` but doesn't work for `db.sqlite3` and `venv/`. It also doesn't work for `__pycache__` but this folder is inside other folders I want to push. That's why solution for this may be different, I would like to solve `db.sqlite3` and `venv/` firstly.

I try these alternatives `venv/` and `venv` and `/venv` at different times but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please share the exact content of the .gitignore file and output of git status when the files you mention are modified?

Comment: Worth noting that adding files to `.gitignore` does not remove them if you have already committed the file.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34435207/6889416

Comment: GaëlJ Thanks for editing and your answer. My file had those 4 rows and my output of git status was really long due to venv. I will share these stuff in my further posts.
NickODell Thanks for your answer. I have tried to create a new repo but I did something wrong again or it didn't work because of .git history. 
@TheIceBear Thanks for your answer. I deleted the .git folder in my project and init again. It worked for a new repo. Same or similar ways I guess.