# How to properly add Flutter build folder and ignore specific files in .gitignore?

Tags: flutter, git, dart, bitbucket

I'm working on a Flutter project and want to configure my .gitignore file to exclude the build/ folder and some specific files from version control. What's the correct syntax for the .gitignore file in a Flutter project to achieve this? Additionally, once I've updated the .gitignore file, what are the steps to commit and push these changes to my Git repository?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/
migrate_working_dir/

# IntelliJ related
*.ipr
*.iws

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Android Studio will place build artifacts here
/android/app/debug
/android/app/profile
/android/app/release

# IOS related

# Xcode
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.pbxuser
*.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/
*.xccheckout

# Build artifacts
build/
DerivedData/

# Flutter-related files
*.lock
!pubspec.lock
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins

# Dart
.pub/
build/
.packages
.dart_tool/

# iOS
Pods/
Podfile.lock
Pods.xcodeproj/
*.xcuserdatad/
*.xcworkspace/
ios/Pods/
ios/.symlinks/
ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/
ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
ios/Flutter/App.framework/
ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
ios/Flutter/Flutter-Structs.h
ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh

# IDE files
.idea/
.vscode/

# Other
*.iml
*.log

# General
.DS_Store
*.sw?
*.out
*.bak
*.swp
*~
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.backup*
*+~
.RELEASE_NOTES.md

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
**/android/key.properties

# iOS/Xcode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**/ios/Pods/

# Web related
**/web/**/.last_build_id

# Exceptions to above rules.
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages 

# Miscellaneous
.flutter-plugins-dependencies

# jks files
*.jks
```

After commiting the .gitignore file. run these commands to remove the already tracked files from the repository. [Credit goes to gtatr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34435207/14466860)

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Drop files from .gitignore"
```