# PIP3 - How to reduce time taken for Building wheel for <lib>?

Tags: pandas, pip, python-wheel

I run pip3 on a Jetson Nano board which has 4 cores ARM A57 and class 1 sdcard. It is ubuntu 18.04 with nVidia repositories.

> pip3 install --user pandas

Takes almost 1 hour!
I have to do it multiple times because I'm building an environment over main OS and dockers. (same behavior on ubuntu and docker image)

HTOP shows that **only 1 core is used** at 100%; 3 others are idling.

I've thought using *--user* would resume "Building Wheel" process...
Any option to get pip3 things go faster?
Can I force Pip3 on multiple cores?
It seems to be a GCC task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip build option to use multicore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228136/pip-build-option-to-use-multicore)

Comment: Is it a package specific option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas), run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` to generate a binary wheel once, upload the wheel to some internal server and install from it every time you need it:

```
pip install http://<internal-server>/path/to/wheels/pandas.whl
```

Binary wheels are installed quite fast; you only need to compile once.

Or run `pip wheel pandas`. Or collect all your requirements into `requirements.txt` and run `pip wheel -r requirements.txt` to build your wheelhouse. To install from it:

```
pip install --index-url=http://<internal-server>/path/to/wheels/ pandas
```