# How to install/compile pip requirements (wheels) faster

Tags: python, arm, cross-compiling, building, buildx

I am currently looking for a solution to speed up our build process. The building of our arm/v7 wheels takes a lot of time with `pip3 install`. I tried to speedup the process by setting the following MAKEFLAG `export MAKEFLAGS="-j$(nproc)" \` at mentioned in [Pip build option to use multicore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228136/pip-build-option-to-use-multicore) to increase the number of used cpu-cores by make. Unfortunately, this has not brought any improvement. Does anyone have any ideas on how to speed up this building-process of the wheels?

Comment: This is rather weird as a question. Normally dependencies should be cached by `pip` after being downloaded/built once. You should be more precise about your needs and show a minimal example.

Comment: We are using this in an ci-pipeline thats also has some other issues. To debug this we need a way to speedup the building-process. Because the pipeline is failing there is no caching of the builded dependencies.

Comment: I can understand what you want and why you want it. Unfortunately I am afraid that this path will be a dead end. IMHO you'd better try to reproduce the ci-pipeline *by hand* on a brand new VM for the process not to be disturbed by pre-existing *things*. Said differently, the building process can possibly be speeded up, but I know no way for that, nor can I imagine any.