# pip install -r requirements.txt produces ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip

I am new to Python and decided to duplicate a virtualenv and work on the new cloned env.

Here's what I did

1. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`,
2. `virtualenv newEnv`
3. `source newEnv/bin/activate`
4. `pip install -r requirements.txt`

However I get the error

```
ImportError: statsmodels requires numpy
```

Manually doing `pip install numpy` I repeated step 4 again and got the error

```
ImportError: statsmodels requires scipy
```

Manually doing `pip install scipy` I repeated step 4 again and got the error

```
ImportError: statsmodels requires pandas
```

How can we get the `pip install -r requirements.txt` to work smoothly without having to manually install the modules?

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015692/pip-fails-to-install-packages-from-requirements-txt?rq=1)

Comment: Does numpy/scipy exist in your requirements.txt?

Comment: @Leonardo.Z Yes numpy/scipy/pandas exist in requirements.txt