# Pip install from requirements file is failing, but installing one by one works

Tags: python, pip, package

I am trying to install a bunch of python dependencies using a requirements.txt file with the following command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The requirements.txt file has the following packages:

```
pep8
selenium
paramiko
soappy
nose
wmi
mock
python-keystoneclient
python-novaclient
python-cinderclient
python-swiftclient
python-glanceclient
python-heatclient
python-neutronclient
```

But when running the pip install command I am getting this error:

```
Downloading/unpacking PrettyTable>=0.7,<0.8 (from python-keystoneclient->-r requ
irements.txt (line 9))
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line
 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
 line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundl
e=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1197, i
n prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1375, i
n unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 54
6, in unpack_http_url
    resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sess
ions.py", line 395, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 23
7, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sess
ions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sess
ions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adap
ters.py", line 381, in send
    raise ProxyError(e)
ProxyError: Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: [Errno 10054] An existing con
nection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\cjmarti2\pip\pip.log
```

But for some reason if I install all packages using `pip install <package>` they all get installed correctly.

A couple of things to consider;
1) since I am in my company's intranet I am setting a proxy using `set https_proxy=https://company-proxy.com:port`. 2) Installing the exact same packages using  requirements.txt in a Linux machine works fine. Any ideas?

**Update:**
I was using Python 2.7 for 64 bits. I uninstalled it and installed the 32 bits, and I no longer had this problem. Looks like the python version was the problem, the 64 bits one for some reason cause problems.

Comment: Did you manage to install all the packages one by one or just few of them ?

Comment: I was able to install all of them

Comment: ok, does your packages has a dependency on each other?

Comment: Maybe your company proxy has some kind of time limit, and the persistent connection from the requests pool has been killed off after some time.

Comment: @schlenk that issomething I also considered, I contacted some of the networking guys here, and according to him this should not be a problem. Of course he can always be wrong :P   But if this was the case I would see the same problem with Linux, however Linux is working fine. :S

Comment: I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015692/pip-fails-to-install-packages-from-requirements-txt, I am not sure if something similar to what is on that question could be happening here. And I am not sure how to determine if that is the problem.