# Can install packages one by one but cannot use pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have establised a virtual enviroment by using python 3.6;
the requirements.txt:

```
alembic==0.9.9
blinker==1.4
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Dance==0.14.0
Flask-DebugToolbar==0.10.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
Flask-OAuth==0.12
Flask-OAuthlib==0.9.4
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
httplib2==0.11.3
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
lazy==1.3
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
oauthlib==2.0.7
python-dateutil==2.7.2
python-editor==1.0.3
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.6
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.33.2
urllib3==1.22
URLObject==2.4.3
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wincertstore==0.2
WTForms==2.1
```

The interesting thing is I can install the package one by one, for example:

```
(mynewflaskenv) D:\pythonProject10>pip install alembic==0.9.9
Collecting alembic==0.9.9
  Using cached alembic-0.9.9.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
Collecting SQLAlchemy>=0.7.6
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.20-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.2 MB 2.2 MB/s
Collecting Mako
  Downloading Mako-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 75 kB 5.1 MB/s
Collecting python-editor>=0.3
  Downloading python_editor-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.9.2
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (16 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for alembic, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: SQLAlchemy, MarkupSafe, Mako, python-editor, six, python-dateutil, alembic
    Running setup.py install for alembic ... done
Successfully installed Mako-1.1.3 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 SQLAlchemy-1.3.20 alembic-0.9.9 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-editor-1.0.4 six-1.15.0
```

But if I use pip install -r requirements.txt:

```
(mynewflaskenv) D:\pythonProject10>pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting alembic==0.9.9
  Using cached alembic-0.9.9.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
Collecting blinker==1.4
  Using cached blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111 kB)
Collecting chardet==3.0.4
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting click==6.7
  Using cached click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
Collecting Flask==1.0.2
  Using cached Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Collecting Flask-Dance==0.14.0
  Using cached Flask_Dance-0.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting Flask-DebugToolbar==0.10.1
  Using cached Flask_DebugToolbar-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (326 kB)
Collecting Flask-Login==0.4.1
  Using cached Flask-Login-0.4.1.tar.gz (14 kB)
Collecting Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
  Using cached Flask_Migrate-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting Flask-OAuth==0.12
  Using cached Flask-OAuth-0.12.tar.gz (6.2 kB)
Collecting Flask-OAuthlib==0.9.4
  Using cached Flask-OAuthlib-0.9.4.tar.gz (34 kB)
Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
  Using cached Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Flask-WTF==0.14.2
  Using cached Flask_WTF-0.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting httplib2==0.11.3
  Using cached httplib2-0.11.3.tar.gz (215 kB)
Collecting idna==2.6
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==0.24
  Using cached itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==2.10
  Using cached Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting lazy==1.3
  Using cached lazy-1.3.zip (15 kB)
Collecting Mako==1.0.7
  Using cached Mako-1.0.7.tar.gz (564 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==1.0
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz (14 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\pythonproject10\mynewflaskenv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\
dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4wzmja7p\\markupsafe\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-in
stall-4wzmja7p\\markupsafe\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"
'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-inf
o-vwktxwrl'
         cwd: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4wzmja7p\markupsafe\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4wzmja7p\markupsafe\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

(mynewflaskenv) D:\pythonProject10>pip install alembic==0.9.9
Collecting alembic==0.9.9
  Using cached alembic-0.9.9.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
Collecting SQLAlchemy>=0.7.6
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.20-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.2 MB 2.2 MB/s
Collecting Mako
  Downloading Mako-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 75 kB 5.1 MB/s
Collecting python-editor>=0.3
  Downloading python_editor-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.9.2
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (16 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for alembic, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: SQLAlchemy, MarkupSafe, Mako, python-editor, six, python-dateutil, alembic
    Running setup.py install for alembic ... done
Successfully installed Mako-1.1.3 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 SQLAlchemy-1.3.20 alembic-0.9.9 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-editor-1.0.4 six-1.15.0

(mynewflaskenv) D:\pythonProject10>pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: alembic==0.9.9 in d:\pythonproject10\mynewflaskenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
(0.9.9)
Collecting blinker==1.4
  Using cached blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111 kB)
Collecting chardet==3.0.4
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting click==6.7
  Using cached click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
Collecting Flask==1.0.2
  Using cached Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Collecting Flask-Dance==0.14.0
  Using cached Flask_Dance-0.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting Flask-DebugToolbar==0.10.1
  Using cached Flask_DebugToolbar-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (326 kB)
Collecting Flask-Login==0.4.1
  Using cached Flask-Login-0.4.1.tar.gz (14 kB)
Collecting Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
  Using cached Flask_Migrate-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting Flask-OAuth==0.12
  Using cached Flask-OAuth-0.12.tar.gz (6.2 kB)
Collecting Flask-OAuthlib==0.9.4
  Using cached Flask-OAuthlib-0.9.4.tar.gz (34 kB)
Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
  Using cached Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Flask-WTF==0.14.2
  Using cached Flask_WTF-0.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting httplib2==0.11.3
  Using cached httplib2-0.11.3.tar.gz (215 kB)
Collecting idna==2.6
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==0.24
  Using cached itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==2.10
  Using cached Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting lazy==1.3
  Using cached lazy-1.3.zip (15 kB)
Collecting Mako==1.0.7
  Using cached Mako-1.0.7.tar.gz (564 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==1.0
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz (14 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\pythonproject10\mynewflaskenv\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\
dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lkdxc8hu\\markupsafe\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-in
stall-lkdxc8hu\\markupsafe\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"
'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-inf
o-fg4ekrqp'
         cwd: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lkdxc8hu\markupsafe\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lkdxc8hu\markupsafe\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Have a google like [Pip install from requirements file is failing, but installing one by one works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336554/pip-install-from-requirements-file-is-failing-but-installing-one-by-one-works) similar question, but different error term, and not be solved. I am wondering can anyone share some solutions, others may also have this problem

Comment: What `pip` version are you running?

Comment: How did you generate your requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the dependencies are conflicting. Installing one by one, you actually end up installing different (conflicting) versions.

Notice:

```
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (16 kB)
```

But your requirements have `MarkupSafe==1.0`

Your best bet would probably be to only pin versions in your `requirements.txt` you *know* you need specific versions of. Try unpinning or using `<` `<=` `>` or `>=` instead of `==` where possible.

It's also worth noting that `pip`'s behavior is changing in regards to conflicting dependencies. So the version of pip you're using can be important, too. Be sure to upgrade pip.